# JPA replacing Many to Many field value of an Entity to a different value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity called `Artwork` which has a member called subjects mapped Many to Many with another entity as follows.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ArtSubject> subjects;
```

Assume that in my `Artwork` table i have a record with subjects values as `(ArtSubject1, ArtSubject2, ArtSubject3)`

I have to replace this value with `(ArtSubject5, ArtSubject6, ArtSubject7)`.

Completely different List.

Curretly if i save an `Artwork` object with new data as `(ArtSubject5, ArtSUbject6, ArtSubject7)`.

JPA appends it with the already existing list and the resulting data is `(ArtSubject1, ArtSubject2, ArtSubject3, ArtSubject5, ArtSUbject6, ArtSubject7)`

I want it to be only `(ArtSubject5, ArtSubject6, ArtSubject7)`

Please find the method where i save the ArtSubject and set it to the Artwork object.

```
ArtWork artwork = new ArtWork();
        List<ArtSubject> subject = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ArtStyle> style = new ArrayList<>();
        Artist artist = new Artist();
        List<ArtCollection> artCollections = new ArrayList<>();

        // Classifying Collections into each category.
        for (Collection collection : collections) {
            String tokens[] = collection.getTitle().split("_");
            if (tokens == null || tokens.length < 2) {
                LOGGER.info("Invalid Collection Type: Collection type {} not recognised", 
                        collection.getTitle());
                continue;
            }
            String collectionType = tokens[0]; 
            switch(collectionType) {
            case "subject":
                ArtSubject artSubject = new ArtSubject(collection.getId(), 
                        collection.getTitle().split("_")[1]);
                subject.add(artSubject);
                artSubjectRepository.save(artSubject);
                break;
            default:
                LOGGER.info("Invalid Collection Type: Collection type {} not recognised", 
                        collection.getTitle());
                break;
            }
        }


        artwork.setSubject(subject);
```

After this i save the artwork as artRepository(CRUD Repository) `artRepository.save(artwork)`
Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `save()` or `saveOrUpdate()` ?

Comment: @Junaid - I am using artworkRepo.save(List<Artwork>)

Comment: Why are you saving the list ?? It should be something like this. 1) `artworkRepo.setSubjects(newSubList);` 2) `session.saveOrUpdate(artworkRepo)`

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you are saving? Are you using spring?

Comment: Can you please provide code of the function where your are saving the list ..!!

Comment: Code added along with the explanation

Comment: As people have said above, use saveOrUpdate.. That will do the trick, Or if you are having too much problems, then delete the entity which already exits, and then use save(I would not recommend this approach)

Answer (score 0):

Try below approaches

For `Collection(List)` (`artwork.setSubjects(new ArrayList<Subject>());`) you have to `clear()` the existing one. This happens because if `Hibernate` loads the entity (and its collections) from DB, it "manages" them, ie. tracks their changes. Generally when using Hibernate it's better not to create any `setters for collections (lists, sets)`. Create only the getter, and clear the collection returned by it, ie:

```
artwork.getSubject().clear();
```

Also, use `orphan deletion` (ie. delete child object when it's removed from collection in the parent). Add `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)` in owning entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am trying to save a person which has oneToMany relationship too...I just use saveOrUpdate, and in frontend even if person edits his details, I call the same method :

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {

        if( session == null) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        session.saveOrUpdate(p);
        session.flush();

    }
```

For saving the entity mapped with one-to-many, i do it this way : here alsso, if canvas details are changed, it does not matter, I call the same method.

```
@Override
public void addCanvas(Canvas canvas, Person person) {
    int id = person.getId();
    if( session == null) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    }else {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    Person person1 = (Person) session.get(Person.class,id);
    person.getCanvas1().add(canvas);
    canvas.setPerson1(person1);
   session.merge(canvas);

    session.flush();
}
```